# Python - String to JSON. Error: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: python, json

I'm very new to python.

I'm forming a json string taking input from various REST calls.

Something like:

```
{
   "-gammaid#10191-":{
      "domain":"Kids Interest",
      "product":"Project1"
   },
   "-gammaid#10382-":{
      "domain":"Weekend Classes",
      "product":"Project2"
   },
   "-gammaid#10442-":{
      "domain":"Knowledge Driven",
      "product":"Project3"
   },
   "-gammaid#10620-":{
      "domain":"Primary Education",
      "product":"Project4"
   },
   "-gammaid#10986-":{
      "domain":"Other Domain",
      "product":"Project5"
   },
   "-gammaid#10987-":{
      "domain":"Kids Interest",
      "product":"Project6"
   },
   "-gammaid#10996-":{
      "domain":"External Classes",
      "product":"Project7"
   },
   "-gammaid#11663-":{
      "domain":"Parent Interaction",
      "product":"Project8"
   }
}
```

As you see each key *gammaid* has in-turn a json structured value.

When I'm running `my_json.get("-gammaid#11663-")`, I'm getting

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Comment: your `my_json` is recognised as a string, whereas you probably want it to be interpreted as a dictionary. the answer to this question is probably what you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/988228/convert-a-string-representation-of-a-dictionary-to-a-dictionary

Comment: What does `type(my_json)` give you @reiley ?

Comment: @KenHBS, thanks. Great insight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to parse it into a dictionary first:

```py
import json

s = 'YOUR JSON STRING'

d = json.loads(s)
print(d["-gammaid#11663-"])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you define it like this:

```
s={
   "-gammaid#10191-":{
      "domain":"Kids Interest",
      "product":"Project1"
   },
   "-gammaid#10382-":{
      "domain":"Weekend Classes",
      "product":"Project2"
   }
```

This is python dict.
So you can just access values like this:

```
s["-gammaid#11663-"]
{'domain': 'Parent Interaction', 'product': 'Project8'}
```

If you need to actually get json object you can do it like this:

```
import json
json.loads(json.dumps(s))
```

Answer (score 0):

Be careful, there are two function in json lib: `json.load**s**()` and `json.load()`;

```
json.load(fs) >> takes file like object 
json.loads(str) >> takes string
```

A nice way to remember it is by the extra `s` means string.